# python cgi.FieldStorage.getvalue() not returning values from POSTed form elements

Tags: python, forms, http, cgi

Using

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
email = form.getvalue('email', 0)
```

Works when form values are sent via GET but not with POST, ie 0 is being assigned to `email`.

What am I doing wrong?

edit: adding html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>login</title></head>
<body>
<form action="cgi.py" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Another module I was using also called cgi.FieldStorage(). As this reads POST data as a file stream it will only read the form data in once. GET is not read as a stream. In this case the other module was called first and extracted the form data before my code above had a chance to look at it.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the HTML you posted, it seems that you forgot something like:

```
<input type="text" name="email"/>
```